# repairing ext3 partitions using windows?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, grub, ext3, arch-linux

I have a linux partition with arch linux installed,i installed windows 7,and now GRUB is gone,i tried installing it again,but it turned out that my ext3 partition is corrupt,i need to fix it before trying to reinstall grub on my harddrive,the question is:

can i repair a partition with the format ext3 using windows 7?

and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You're better off booting to a live CD and running fsck on it from that.